# Regex match base64 encoding in email subject

Tags: java, regex

I try to match a regex with java and can't find the right regex

I want to match =?utf-8?B?XXXXXXXX=?= in

=?utf-8?B?UmVtaW5kZXI=?=

I tried :

```
s.matches("=\\?utf\\-8\\?B\\?.*=\\?=");
s.matches("=\\?utf-8\\?B\\?.*=\\?=");
```

Comment: If `s` is the whole subject, you need to use `contains()` instead of `matches()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure? Which version of Java are you using?

I've made a basic test with your scenario and it works...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String input = "=?utf-8?B?UmVtaW5kZXI=?=";
    String input2 = "irege";

    String regex = "=\\?utf\\-8\\?B\\?.*=\\?=";

    System.out.println(input.matches(regex));
    System.out.println(input2.matches(regex));

}
```

Console output:

```
true
false
```

Comment: I've tested with java 1.6.0_22 and java 1.7.0_03 and the result is the same

Comment: I've retested because input variable was with the "mask" value and not the original input, however the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

This does it:

```
"=\\?utf-8\\?B\\?[^=]*=\\?="
```